# From a page in AstroJS [plugin:astro] location is not defined

Tags: javascript, dom, astrojs

In `pages/index.astro` if I try

```
---
console.log(location.href)
---
```

Then I get
[image]

Error in text:

> [plugin:astro] location is not defined
>
> export statements in `.astro` files do not have access to local
> variable declarations, only imported values.

How can I access or import location from a AstroJs page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location` is a browser global. It doesn't exist in Node, which your Astro site will be built in.

Use `Astro.url.href` instead, the docs for which can be found here: https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/#astrourl